# How to set the right permissions of my private ssh_key on start of my docker container?

Tags: docker

At Each start of my docker container i got the error message:

```
Permissions 0644 for '/root/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
```

So i set the right permissions at each start with the following command:

```
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

But i want to make it automatic,
so i tried to set the permissions in the Dockerfile at the **RUN** instruction and directly in the docker run command but it didn't work.
I added this in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and this in the docker run command:

```
docker run [...] ; docker run chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Can you help me to run a command directly in my docker container ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have changed your Dockerfile, have you tried to rebuild the image ?

The command used to rebuild image from Dockerfile is the following: `docker build -t name .` where the dot is the path with the Dockerfile, and name is the name of your container :)